# Pandas copy is changing the original dataframe, even with copy(deep=True)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code that seeks to create 2 separate tables from 1 dataframe. The tables have different filters applied.
What I am finding is that once the first filter is applied, the original dataframe 'changes'.

```
df_orig = pd.read_excel('JRMaster.xlsm')
df_orig.columns = map(str.upper, df_orig.columns)
df_orig['SYSTEM'] = df_orig['SYSTEM'].str.upper()
df_orig['STATUS'] = df_orig['STATUS'].str.upper()

df = df_orig.copy(deep=True)
df_copy_all = df_orig.copy(deep=True)

df = df[(df['DATE PAID'].dt.month.between(10,10)) & (df['DATE PAID'].dt.year == 2020)]
df2 = df_copy_all[(df_copy_all['DATE SENT'].dt.month.between(10,10)) & (df['DATE SENT'].dt.year == 2020)]
```

df and df2 should should 2 different results, but the output is the same.
I have tried df.copy() and df.copy(deep=True)

using Pandas 1.0.5 and Python 3.6

some forums state that this is a bug, but I want to check if there is a work around or fix to this.

an alternative I thought about is to read the original excel document into multiple dataframes, but this seems unsustainable and resource heavy.

EDIT:

Sample Data below:

```
System  DATE SENT   STATUS  DATE PAID
0   One 2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
1   One 2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
2   THREE   2020-10-01  SR  2020-10-07
3   One 2020-10-01  DUP NaT
4   One 2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
5   One 2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
6   THREE   2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
7   One 2020-10-01  DUP NaT
8   THREE   2020-10-01  AR  2020-07-31
9   THREE   2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
10  One 2020-10-01  AR  2020-08-21
11  One 2020-10-01  DUP NaT
12  One 2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
13  One 2020-10-01  DUP NaT
14  One 2020-10-01  DUP NaT
15  One 2020-10-01  DUP NaT
16  One 2020-10-01  DUP NaT
17  THREE   2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
18  One 2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
19  One 2020-10-01  OPEN    NaT
```

Comment: I think this is data related problem, is possible add some data sample? What is `print (df_orig.head())` ?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the data. I manually filter within the excel document and I get the desired results.

Comment: Hmmm, Ok, so please add some data for test.

Comment: Because I think this is XY problem. Because if use `df[(df['DATE PAID'].dt.month.between(10,10)) & (df['DATE PAID'].dt.year == 2020)]` and `df[(df['DATE SENT'].dt.month.between(10,10)) & (df['DATE SENT'].dt.year == 2020)]` output is different? I guess not.

Comment: Here is different question - if same it means there are datetimes with year == 2020 and months 10 for both columns in same positions (maybe days are different, maybe not), It is expected?

Comment: @jezrael, I have added sample data to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is actually with a typo:

```
df2 = df_copy_all[(df_copy_all['DATE SENT'].dt.month.between(10,10)) & (df['DATE SENT'].dt.year == 2020)]
```

should be

```
df2 = df_copy_all[(df_copy_all['DATE SENT'].dt.month.between(10,10)) & (df2['DATE SENT'].dt.year == 2020)]
```

> the error was at: df2['DATE SENT'], I had df['DATE SENT']

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `deepcopy` doesn't work with `pandas`.

Refer to this [`Deep copying in Pandas`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17406).

Comment: damn this is bad - are there any solutions ?

Comment: @qbbq Not too sure about it.